# Index.php is ordering posts strangely

Tags: posts, loop

`Index.php` has the loop and I'm adding HTML at intervals, but when I preview the post list page, the order is incorrect. I've tried a different loop, and I've also tried `query_posts` & without, but nothing is changing the post order.

You can see the link [here](http://185.17.150.73/~howardshooter15/wp/index.php/blog/).

Here is the code from the `index.php`:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main row" role="main">
<?php $i = 0;
$posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=post_date&order=desc' ); 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();
        if ( $i == 0 ) { 
            echo "<h1 class='col-md-12 section-title large-title'><span>Newest Article</span></h1>";
        } else if ( $i == 1 ) {
            echo "<h1 class='col-md-12 section-title medium-title'><span>Recent Articles</span></h1>";
        } else if ( $i == 3 ) {
            echo "<h1 class='col-md-12 section-title small-title'><span>Older Articles</span></h1>";
        } ?>
        <div class="post <?php if ( $i == 0 ) { ?> col-md-12 large-post<?php } 
            else if ( $i < 3 ) { ?> medium-post col-md-6 <?php } 
            else { ?> col-md-4 small-post<?php } 
            ?> post<?php echo $i; ?>"><div class="post-inner">
            <div class="info"><div class="info-inner">
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
                <div class="blog-post">
                    <?php if ( $i < 3 ) {
                        the_excerpt();
                    } ?>
                </div>
            </div></div>
        </div></div>
        <?php $i++; 
    endwhile; 
else :
    get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' );
endif; ?>
</main>
```

Comment: what do you mean by ordering your posts strangely? `query_posts` is definitely the wrong way to change the main query, never use `query_posts`. disable plugins and switch to a default core theme to see if the problem persists.

Comment: What's `$query_string`?

Comment: thanks for the comments everyone - I've changed to this while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); normal loop and it's still in the wrong order it's meant to be newest to oldest but it's in a random order

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't modify the main query like that. Instead, make a secondary loop:

```
// The Query
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'desc',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Do output
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

[Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query, not `query_posts` or changing the main query with a custom one

Comment: I'm just wanting a list of posts ordered by date newest first I've removed the variable and it's still appearing in the incorrect order